# Android waveshare touchscreen

Tags: android, driver, raspberry-pi3, touchscreen

Im trying to install an android touchscreen driver ... i have a raspberry pi 3 and i installed emteria android it ... i bought a waveshare touchscreen https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/10.1inch_HDMI_LCD#Method_1._Driver_installation.

I was able to fix the resolution and the screen shows fine but the touch doesnt work i tried installing the driver but it was meant for ubuntu and it doesnt work on android. Any idea how i can fix my issue with the touchscreen?

Comment: You probably need to get the driver source code and tweak it so it works on Emteria's Android fork.

Comment: Waveshare said they "won't provide any source code because other companies can copy very fast". Here is the source code for a 7 inch hack which might work for you (read the webpage). https://github.com/derekhe/waveshare-7inch-touchscreen-driver  ALSO see https://github.com/110yd/wshare-touchscreen

Comment: ill check it out and see if it works ... i will comeback tonight with the results thank you @JonGoodwin

Comment: @JonGoodwin Thank you for the github.com/derekhe/waveshare-7inch-touchscreen-driver but it didnt work, i dont have apt-get to install python3 and i have no idea what to use instead.

Comment: Yes the Python solution is not good, I intended it as inspiration for you to write your own. Waveshare I assume are a small company with limited resources and do not respond, or say no on their web site. The C solution is also not good (and tiny) but can be built (I guess) but is in the authors own words "buggy". What can I say, you want a driver that the hardware manufacturer is not (as of now) prepared to compile for you on a new platform. Don't buy their products or use the platform they support. It could be hacked, but as you see, the people prepared to do that are few and far between.

Comment: Wait, revert, go to another product is all I can suggest. All development costs money in the world outside of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Use this below touch screen driver :

https://github.com/derekhe/waveshare-7inch-touchscreen-driver

and use these below commands :

```
git clone https://github.com/derekhe/waveshare-7inch-touchscreen-driver

    cd waveshare-7inch-touchscreen-driver
    chmod +x install.sh
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo ./install.sh
    sudo restart
```

Comment: While you are quite welcome to build, add value and answer based on my (researched) comment of the Python solution, you seem to have cut-and-pasted from the linked web page (thirty seconds work), and not added anything (the fact you need to install a Python interpreter, the question is about Emteria not Ubuntu). This kind of mercenary effort for a bounty should be below you and voted on accordingly. It is also common courtesy on this site to acknowledge where your inspiration builds from.

Comment: This doesnt work, i cant use apt-get or most of the commands in that install.sh file.As the above comment stated this was taken right out of the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Hi can u install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en it provides a base system that has `apt-get` and also some C tools for building so maybe you can try @JonGoodwin answer.
Hope it helps, what you are trying to do is very interesting.

Comment: trying that now ... will come back in a few with updates

Comment: I was unable to run the c file it produced an error because of a missing dependency and im unable to install the dependency,https://github.com/tuomasjjrasanen/libsuinput when i try to run configure.ac it tells me permission denied even if im su

Comment: and did u try the @chandrakant sharma solution?

Comment: yes, i installed python and pip and still get errors from the python script written ...